# Django how to get first 10 characters of a TextField as a string?

Tags: python, django, string

Please pardon my question, I am a beginner in Python and Django.

I have a `class Response` here, which inherits from `models.Model`. One of the fields is `response_content`, a `TextField`. I have a function `__str__` which is supposed to return a string representation of the object. The first part of this string is that object's `id`, then a space separator, then the field `self.author_name`, then a pipe separator, then after that I want to display the first 10 characters of the `self.response_content` as a string. I do not want to dump the whole `self.response_context` into the string, because this is a `TextField` with `max_length=4000`, so it can get very big! I want to have just the first 10 characters of this field to be displayed as a string, so that I can just look and immediately remember what was the rest of the `response_content` from these displayed characters. That is how I can tell apart individual `Response`s.

I want to replace the `???` with the necessary expression. I do not yet know the syntax well enough, so please don't hate me for asking this question.

This is my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Response(models.Model):
    # Default field options: (null=False, blank=False)
    # Bu default, Django gives each model the following field:
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #
    # The name of the author.
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    # The author's email address.
    author_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    # The date and time when this response was made.
    response_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # The text content of the response.
    response_content = models.TextField(max_length=4000)

    # This is used for returning a string description of the Response for the
    # admin interface.
    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.id) + " " + self.author_name + "|" + ???)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice the string with `self.response_content[:10]`.

In your case:

```
def __str__(self):
    return (str(self.id) + " " + self.author_name + "|" + self.response_content[:10])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `truncatechars` filter from Django:

```
{{ value|truncatechars:7 }}
```

If value is "Joel is a slug", the output will be "Joel i…".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by two ways

1. Return `response_content` by just slicing as below.

```
def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.id) + " " + self.author_name + "|" + self.resonse_content[:10])
```

2. By using Django default filter namely `truncatechars`.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import truncatechars

class Response(models.Model):
...
    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.id) + " " + self.author_name + "|" + truncatechars(self.resonse_content, 10))
```